# Why am I getting "tiff page 1 not found" Lebtonica warning in Tesseract?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tiff

I just started using [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#run-tesseract-for-training).

I am following the instructions described [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#run-tesseract-for-training).

I have created a test image like this:

```
training/text2image --text=test.txt --outputbase=eng.Arial.exp0 --font='Arial' --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts
```

Now I want to train the Tesseract like follows:

```
tesseract eng.Arial.exp0.tif eng.Arial.exp0 box.train
```

Here is the output that I have:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.00 with Leptonica
Page 1
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile:     112
   Found 112 good blobs.
Generated training data for 21 words
Warning in pixReadMemTiff: tiff page 1 not found
```

This prevents the creation of `fontfile.tr` file. I have tried continuing by ignoring the warning, but when creating the char-sets I get an awefull content:

```
unicharset_extractor lang.fontname.exp0.box

"58
NULL 0 NULL 0
Joined 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0     # Joined [4a 6f 69 6e 65 64 ]
|Broken|0|1 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0    # Broken
T 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0  # T [54 ]
h 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0  # h [68 ]
e 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0  # e [65 ]
( 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0  # ( [28 ]
q 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0  # q [71 ]
u 0 0,255,0,255,0,0,0,0,0,0 NULL 0 0 0  # u [75 ]
..."
```

Here is the version I am using:

```
tesseract 3.04.00
 leptonica-1.72
  libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0) : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug, I'm using v4.00.00alpha and I get

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.00.00alpha with Leptonica
Page 1
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile:     100
   Found 100 good blobs.
Generated training data for 21 words
```